# SQL - Trigger para enviar email quando é realizado update

Tags: sql, trigger

Bom dia, necessito de ajuda no seguinte:

Tenho um trigger para enviar email quando quando é realizado um update, mas estou com um problema!

Sempre que a tabela tem update é uma grid inteira que é carregada e envia emails a todas linhas que contenham o campo fechado = 1

Eu queria comparar com a tabela ao criar o cursor mas não estou a ter sucesso!

Segue o trigger de seguida!

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[TRI_fp_email] 
ON [dbo].[fp]
for UPDATE
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM inserted WHERE fechado = 1)

declare @no2 as numeric(5,0), @email2 as varchar(100), @stamp as varchar(25)

DECLARE C_FP CURSOR

for SELECT fpStamp FROM inserted  WHERE fechado = 1 


open C_FP
FETCH NEXT FROM C_FP  INTO @stamp

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN 

SET @email2 = (SELECT top 1 us.email FROM fp join us on fp.no = us.clbno  WHERE fpstamp = @stamp group by us.email)
SET @no2 = (SELECT top 1 fp.no FROM fp join us on fp.no = us.clbno  WHERE fpstamp = @stamp group by fp.no)

    EXEC dbo.emailVaiFerias @no2, @email2, @stamp 

FETCH NEXT FROM C_FP INTO @stamp
END

CLOSE C_FP
DEALLOCATE C_FP 

end
```

Já tentei desta forma mas sem sucesso!

> for SELECT i.fpStamp FROM inserted i  JOIN u_fp_temp f on f.fpstamp = i.fpstamp WHERE i.fechado = 1 and f.fechado = 0

Desde já obrigado pela ajuda!

### Editado!

Acabei por descobrir que o problema é que o trigger é executado então a comparação a tabela que tenho que realizar não se aplica por estar já editada!

Existe forma de realizar antes do update?

### Editado !

Resolvido, criei novo campo na tabela realizei no programa 2 updates a mesma um com o que pretendo atualizar na tabela e outro para atualizar o campo de diferenciação da tabela de forma a conseguir o pretendido!

Caso tenham sugestões melhores agradeço que partilhem!

Comment: Não entendi direito o que vc quer. Consegue ser mais claro ou objetivo?

Comment: Basicamente é o seguinte esta trigger é executada sempre que uma tabela numa aplicação em vfp é executada e realiza o update na tabela que tem o trigger! 
E esta a mandar emails em duplicado porque não consigo comparar o inserted com a própria tabela

Comment: A Grid em VFP é para aprovação das ferias e com o trigger pretendo enviar um email quando são aprovadas, mas como o vfp realiza o update a todas as linhas esta sempre a enviar emails mesmo as que já enviou. 
estou a tentar ao carregar o cursor só com as que tem diferença mas sem sucesso.
espero ter sido mais claro com o que pretendo!

Comment: Em vez de recuperar todos os registros da tabela inserted  aonde fechado = 1 por que não verificar se apenas no registro alterado fechado = 1?

Comment: Mas como posso fazer isso?